# Проблемы после компиляции cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Добрый день! Попробовал скомпилировать свою небольшую прогу (да, это надо с:).
При включении exe-шника ругается на "ImportError: cannot import '_methods' "
Мой код включает Pyqt5, matplotlib.

Вот setup.py :

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(
    name = "Graphics",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Extract_Graphics",
    executables = [Executable("Gr.py", base = base)]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Выкини cx_Freeze** *Установи PyInstaller! и забудь про ошибки.*
**pip install PyInstaller**

Comment: Спасибо за совет.
Но собранная программа не запускается. В чем могут быть проблемы?

Comment: Если ещё не разобрались , запускать нужно файл из дириктории dist и если есть упаковщик upx либо другой  то удалите его...

Comment: Запускал файл из директории dist, на доли секунды моргало окошко командной строки и больше ничего не происходило.
Пробовал собирать в один файл (--onefile), получалось аналогично, сборка завершена, при включение .ехе один раз моргнет окно командной строки.
В чем причины?

Comment: C:\Users\саня\AppData\Local\Temp в этой директории есть папки с такими названиями  _MEI9802 попробуйте все их удалить у меня виндовс 7 python 3.5.2 всё собирается без проблем с такими библиотеками как  PyQt5 , pandas , tkinter и опять про upx у меня с ним возникали такие проблемы которые вы описываете

Comment: Попробовал собрать скрипт с библиотекой matplotlib так PyInstaller выдал кучу ошибок возможно проблема именно в matplotlib хотя график запускается

Comment: Всё заработало удалил библиотеку jinja2 и исправил gi там синтаксис 2 питона  вообще я этой ерунды в питоне непонимаю зачем pip скачивает недорабатанные библиотеки с кучами ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Нужен дополнительный импорт matplotlib.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

if sys.platform == "win32":
     base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "Graphics",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Extract_Graphics",
    executables = [Executable(
                script = "Gr.py",
                base = base
                )],
    options = {"build_exe": 
                    {"packages": 
                        [
                            "matplotlib",
                        ]
                    }
                },
)
```